# How do i replace "-" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let say the variable name is

```
var name = "Stack overflow is great";
```

I want to change it to

```
var name = "Stack-overflow-is-great";
```

I did this

```
name.replace(/ /g, '-');
```

and here is the result

```
var name = "Stack-overflow-is-great-";
```

There is an extra dash at the end, how do i prevent from the last dash to appear in my string?

Comment: make sure you dont have any spaces at the end. Just as a work around you can do name.replace(/-$/g,'');

Comment: try `replace(/\s/g, "-")`

Comment: for me it works properly, you might be missing whitespaces which are there just trim it like `name.trim().replace(/ /g, '-');`.

Comment: Not reproducible with the code you provided.

Comment: If `name` does not have space at the end then your solution is working find -- ***[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/vkbx91a9/1/)***

Comment: Just to note, you can test regex using http://regex101.com - Input your string and then you can see exactly how regex will react to your string.

Comment: By the way this code is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, your actual input contains trailing spaces, because your example works ok.

Remove trailing space with trim function as I've showed in snippet below.

```js
var name = "Stack overflow is great ";
var newName = name.trim().replace(/ /g, '-');
console.log(newName);
```

Comment: Stack Overflow's snippet window has a handy console mirror, so please use `console.log()` rather than `alert()` for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is to exclude the last dash.

```js
            var name = "Stack overflow is awsome "
            name = name.replace(/ /g,'-');
            console.log(name);
            var pos = name.lastIndexOf('-');
            console.log(pos);
            name = name.substring(0,pos);

            console.log(name);
```

Comment: Did you test this on cases where there isn't a dash at the end of the string?

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the return value from the ***replace()*** function to a variable. 
The ***replace()*** function does not change the String object it is called on. It simply returns a new string.

```js
    var name  = "Stack overflow is great";

    name = name.replace(/ /g, '-');

    console.log(name);
```

Comment: this is just similar to the question asked

Answer (score 0):

Using concat() function you can add expression at the end of the string .

```
(function(){
var name = "Stack overflow is great";
name=name.replace(/ /g, '-');
var name=name.concat(expression);

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `endWith` to check if your `name` has space at the End.

```js
var name = "Stack overflow is great ";
if(name.endsWith(" ")){
 name = name.substring(0, name.length -1);
 }
console.log(name.replace(/ /g, '-'));
```